# What is $\mathbb{F}^{2, 2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, cross-product, scalar-fields

If $\mathbb{F}$ is a scalar field, what is meant by $\mathbb{F}^{2,2}$? Is this the same as $\mathbb{F}^2 \times \mathbb{F}^2$? Or is it $\mathbb{F}^2 \otimes \mathbb{F}^2$?

Comment: I would probably say the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb{F}$, but it would depend on context.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelBiro ... No paper or book should use that notation without first saying what it means.

Comment: That makes sense, given that the context is a homework problem which asks to show that a set of $2 \times 2$ matrices is not a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^{2,2}$. I think that's probably what is meant actually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2$ is the set with two elements then $\Bbb F^2$ is the set of all function $2\to\Bbb F$ and $F^{2,2}$ could be the set of all functions $$2\to \Bbb F^2.$$

Comment: or all functions mapping $2 \times 2$ to $\mathbb{F}$, which I think is equivalent.

Comment: yes! $2\to \Bbb F$ is the set of all pair $(a,b)$ of ${\Bbb F}\times\Bbb F$ and $2\to\Bbb F^2$ all the pair of pairs $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)$